# How to enable python3 in vim8

Tags: centos7

This is python3 installed using scl tool.
And I am permanently using python3 by adding "source scl_source enable rh-python36" to /etc/profile.

vim version => vim8
linux = CentOS7

How can I enable'-python3'?
Or do I need to install python3 again?

Comment: Do you need to enable python3 syntax in vim8?

Comment: You can also work with vim 7.4